# Require WP login for outside access

Tags: wp-login-form

I am building an intranet site for my company. The goal is to have people within the building have open access but outside the building require a username and password. I have looked through a couple options with using an htaccess file, or possibly a combination of plugins. Can anyone point me in the direction to do this. I was thinking of doing something along the lines of IP address based requiring of WP authentication but I have not figured out how to accomplish that as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Apache and don't specifically need users to log in via WordPress, you can use HTTP Authentication.

This [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102763/apache-basic-authentication-except-for-those-allowed) thread is what you're looking for.

Also, check out the documentation for Apache's [HTTP Authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) and [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this thanks. I was thinking of actually using the WordPress login. That way people can actually sign up on their own, although we may have to do something like you mentioned because even then we want to be able to control people signing up (approvals, and revocation).

Comment: In that case, I'd just use the standard WP user accounts to log in, even if they're coming from the intranet. For one, you can easily control rights/approvals/revocation, and two, how would WP know which user is which based solely on IP? Assuming DHCP, there isn't a way (that I know of) to guarantee a user's identity via IP and they'd have to log in anyway.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. The reason I would use IP based is if they are accessing the site from within the building they would be able to explore the site openly. What I'm looking to also do is for any outside IP address to force them to login to the site. That's the part I'm unsure about. IP is only thing I can think of for determining their location.